# SKNode Changing Direction on Flat Surface Unexpectedly in Swift 2

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I am trying to make a SpriteKit game in swift similar to Mario Brothers or Pitfall.  In this game, there are zoo keepers that move back and forth in the horizontal direction, i.e. along the x-coordinate axis.  The zoo keeper is walking on a base referred to as platform nodes.  When the zoo keeper collides with a platform in front of them, for example a crate or a zoo cage, the zoo keeper turn and walk the other way.  The zoo keeper is expected to move over the ground.  The game uses the built in physics properties.  The zoo keeper has a restitution of 1.0.  I start the zoo keeper with a small impulse.  In the update function, I set the velocity to zero in the y direction and set the x velocity to the current zoo keeper x velocity such that the zoo keeper doesn't bounce in the y direction and continues in whatever x velocity/direction they were moving.  I set the y velocity to zero such that if the zoo keeper walk off a higher level platform, I don't don't want them to bounce in the y direction.  The zoo keeper starts off in his daily rounds and moves to the right across 8 ground platform units, bounces off of a crate, turns around and starts walking the other direction.  Although, on the way back the after walking over 3 ground platform units, the zoo keeper unexpectedly collides with the ground platform that he previously already walked over and turns around.  Each time I re-run the game in xCode, the collision may occur in different places although once running, the collision occurs consistently at the same place.  If I give the zoo keeper a lot more initial impulse, the issue goes away although then my zoo keeper moves way too fast.  The ground nodes are all the same size and placed with a for loop at the same y position.  Here is an example of the zoo keeper (CharacterNode) walking (contacting) ground a node just prior to turning around and contacting a ground node (PlatformNode) that turns the node around, but shouldn't.

Node that is walked over (Before):

Printing description of contact._bodyA:
 type: representedObject:[ name:'Platform' position:{974.613037109375, 24.98663330078125} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{962.11297607421875, 12.487000465393066}, {25, 25}}]
Printing description of contact._bodyB:
 type: representedObject:[ name:'ZooKeeper' position:{1000.2339477539062, 62.757087707519531} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{987.7340087890625, 37.756999969482422}, {25, 50}}]

Ground node that causes the unexpected blocking:

Printing description of contact._bodyA:
 type: representedObject:[ name:'Platform' position:{774.5714111328125, 24.986606597900391} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{762.07098388671875, 12.487000465393066}, {25, 25}}]
Printing description of contact._bodyB:
 type: representedObject:[ name:'ZooKeeper' position:{749.27301025390625, 62.757034301757812} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{736.77301025390625, 37.756999969482422}, {25, 50}}]

Here is the code that I believe is relevant.  I create the platforms and zoo keepers by reading a file of integer x, y coordinates from excel files, scale the objects and place them in sknodes with skspritenodes.  The "pattern" for a platform could be 1 ground block, two, three, ten, a stair pattern, etc.  The ground pattern is 10 consecutive boxes.  All platforms are exactly the same size (25x25).  Although if you look a the print description, precision appears to be slightly off.

Platform logic:  The pattern for a ground node is a set of 10 single ground units placed side by side, i.e., same y coordinate and spaced by 1 unit in the x direction.

```
let kScenePositionScale: CGFloat = 25 // scale all scene positions read from a file by this factor
let kPlatformSizeScale:CGFloat = 0.5
let kCharacterSizeScale:CGFloat = 0.25

    for platform in platformArray {
        for patternItem in platform.pattern.patternItemArray {
            let positionX = platform.xCoordinate + patternItem.xCoordinate
            let positionY = platform.yCoordinate + patternItem.yCoordinate
            let platformNode = SceneObject.createPlatformAtPosition(CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY), ofType: PlatformType(rawValue: patternItem.imageName)!)
            foregroundNode.addChild(platformNode)
        }
    }

    class func createPlatformAtPosition(position: CGPoint, ofType type: PlatformType) -> PlatformNode {
    let node = PlatformNode()
    node.position = position
    node.name = kPlatformNodeName
    node.platformType = type

    var sprite: SKSpriteNode

    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: type.rawValue)
    sprite.setScale(kPlatformSizeScale)

    node.addChild(sprite)
    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    node.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategoryBitmask.Platform
    node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


    return node
}
```

Zoo Keeper:  I only use the contact bitmask to be able to print the contact causing the unexpected turn around feature.  The pattern is irrelevant at this point for the zoo keeper.  The pattern is at 0,0

```
    // for each item in the character array
    for character in characterArray {
        for patternItem in character.pattern.patternItemArray {
            let positionX = character.xCoordinate + patternItem.xCoordinate
            let positionY = character.yCoordinate + patternItem.yCoordinate
            let characterNode = Character.createCharacterAtPosition(CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY), ofType: CharacterType(rawValue: patternItem.imageName)!, ofMotionType: character.motionType)
            foregroundNode.addChild(characterNode)
            characterNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(1.0, 0.0))
        }
    }

    class func createCharacterAtPosition(position: CGPoint, ofType type: CharacterType, ofMotionType motionType: CharacterMotionType) -> CharacterNode {
    let node = CharacterNode()
    node.position = position
    node.name = type.rawValue // named after the character type
    node.characterMotionType = motionType
    node.textureArray = loadPrimaryAtlas(type.rawValue)

    var sprite: SKSpriteNode

    sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: node.textureArray[0])

    // anchor at the feet
    sprite.setScale(kCharacterSizeScale)

    node.sprite = sprite

    node.addChild(sprite)
    node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.frame.size)
    node.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    node.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0 // bounciness
    node.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0 // keep the character moving if needed
    node.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
    node.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategoryBitmask.Character
    node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategoryBitmask.Platform //Collision will occur when hero hits land
    node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategoryBitmask.Platform //Contact will be detected when make a contact with land and fruit


    return node
}
```

Comment: You want restitution to be 0 if you do not want bounciness,  it could be what is causing your issues,  sprite hits ground, bounces, you think you reset it, but the calculations of the physics get thrown off, and then he moves in opposite direction

Comment: I do want the zoo keepers to collide and bounce off of objects that they run into.  Consider a ball rolling back and forth in a box.  The collision with the floor keeps the ball from falling through the ground, and doesn't cause the ball to change x-axis direction (left/right).  Only the sides of the box should cause the ball to change direction in the x-axis direction.  I am using restitution to allow the physics engine to determine where they should be moving.

Comment: use begin contact to alter the x direction, restitution would be like driving a car into a wall, sure the car bounces back, but will not change directions with the bounce

Comment: didBeginContact is difficult as the object below the zoo keeper is the same object type as what is left and right. I tried this approach at first and it gets very complicated for other more complex objects that jump and aren't rectangles.  Related to the car analogy, my hero works like a car and is intended to bounce slightly after hitting a platform on its side. The hero stops in the middle of the floor similar to the way the zoo keeper bounces.  It's the same root cause I believe.

Comment: it is really not tough to use didBeginContact,  you just check if the platform node is beneath the zookeeper, and ignore it, otherwise it is a side hit. Also, you could give a platform a parent node 2 nodes with 2 physics bodies, once that has an edgeloop so that the sprite can walk without worrying about didbegin being called, and another that is shaped like H, so that only side collisions get registered

Comment: The didBeginContact option seems to defeat the purpose of the physics engine and letting the physics engine manage collisions appropriately.  For argument, lets ignore the end/side blocks, the root issues still exists in that the zoo keeper walking on a flat set of equally sized blocks randomly turns around at some block interfaces.  This turning around is what I want to resolve.  As noted in a comment above, I have the same issue with the hero character that has a lower restitution.  I need to solve the collision issue or I will end up coding around it for every moving and colliding node.

Comment: You are already defeating the purpose of the physics engine by changing the velocity.  Your issue is you are colliding with the ground.  Here is what is happening,  gravity takes effect, which pushes you into the block for some reason(maybe a floating point rounding error, who knows), which causes restitution to push you out of the block in the reverse direction, then while this is happening at some unspecified point you reset the velocity in the  y direction